# Covert boost::asio::ip::address_v4 to string

Tags: c++, boost, type-conversion, boost-asio

Currently I'm looking for a way to convert a `boost::asio::ip::address_v4()` to a `string`. Is there a way to accomplish this? The method comes from the ipv4_header.hpp on the [boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/icmp/ipv4_header.hpp)

**Update**: i have tried `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string(ipv4_hdr.source_address())`, but I was unsuccessful

Comment: You need to learn to read documentation, there is a [to_string()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/to_string.html) function.

Comment: I already found that, it was right in the documentation but it doesn't work. I have `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string(ipv4_hdr.source_address())`. It gives: `Error: no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string" matches the arguments list arguments types are: (boost::asio::ip::address_v4)`

Comment: Try `ipv4_hdr.source_address().to_string();`

Comment: Just before your post I tried the same and it worked! If you want to add this as an answer, than I it clear that his has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`address_v4` has a member function [to_string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/to_string.html).

The function you were calling, `boost::asio::ip::address_v4 source_address() const` returns an `address_v4` object by value. Non-static member functions must be called on objects, therefore, you can call `to_string()` on the object returned from the function: `ipv4_hdr.source_address().to_string();`. Note also the member function is marked `const` which allows you to call it on constant objects.

The error was for two reasons:

1. `to_string()` has two overloads. One accepts zero arguments and the other accepts an `boost::system::error_code` reference. You were trying to pass an `address_v4` object as an argument to `to_string()`, which is incorrect (no such overload exists).
2. The syntax `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string(...)` will only work if `to_string()` is a static member function. Since `to_string()` is a non-static member function you need the `.` dot operator to call a member function on the object instance, i.e. `.to_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

This Works.

```
unsigned long ip_lb;
...
ip::address peerIp = ip::address_v4(ip_lb)
cout << peerIp.to_string
```